# Cakephp find's returning null

Tags: sql, cakephp

hi all I'm trying to do two things with a find, 
the model disputes belongsTo invoices.

find all invoices where

`invoice.receiver_id=account.id`

and

`dispute.invoice_id=invoice.id`

currently the array is returning null when I debug. There should be 2 results in the find statement

here is the code in my disputes controller

```
public function index_admin(){


    $id = $this->Auth->User('account_id');

    $receiver = $this->Invoice->find('all',array(
    'conditions'=>array("AND"=>array(
    'Invoice.id'=>'Dispute.invoice_id',
    'receiver_id'=>$id))));

        $this->set('id',$id);
        $this->set('receiver', $receiver);
  }
```

This is in the disputes controller, as I want to print out a list about invoices  that have disputes.

```
Query   Error   Affected    Num. rows   Took (ms)
1   SELECT `Invoice`.`id`, `Invoice`.`scheduled`, `Invoice`.`paid`, `Invoice`.`sender_id`, `Invoice`.`receiver_id`, `Invoice`.`template_id`, `Invoice`.`created`, `Invoice`.`expiry_date`, `Invoice`.`total_amount`, `ReceiverAccount`.`id`, `ReceiverAccount`.`street`, `ReceiverAccount`.`city`, `ReceiverAccount`.`postcode`, `ReceiverAccount`.`state`, `ReceiverAccount`.`country`, `ReceiverAccount`.`active`, `ReceiverAccount`.`account_name`, `ReceiverAccount`.`abn`, `SenderAccount`.`id`, `SenderAccount`.`street`, `SenderAccount`.`city`, `SenderAccount`.`postcode`, `SenderAccount`.`state`, `SenderAccount`.`country`, `SenderAccount`.`active`, `SenderAccount`.`account_name`, `SenderAccount`.`abn`, `Template`.`id`, `Template`.`name`, `Template`.`description`, `Template`.`account_id`, `Template`.`active` FROM `pra`.`invoices` AS `Invoice` LEFT JOIN `pra`.`accounts` AS `ReceiverAccount` ON (`Invoice`.`receiver_id` = `ReceiverAccount`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `pra`.`accounts` AS `SenderAccount` ON (`Invoice`.`sender_id` = `SenderAccount`.`id`) LEFT JOIN `pra`.`templates` AS `Template` ON (`Invoice`.`template_id` = `Template`.`id`) WHERE `Invoice`.`id` = 'Dispute.invoice_id' AND `Invoice`.`receiver_id` = 2
```

EDIT ---------------------

```
invoices tables has - id, sender_id, receiver_id, amount, expiry_date, created, paid
disputes table has - id, dispute_date, comment, active
```

the disputes model looks like this

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Invoice' => array(
            'className' => 'Invoice',
            'foreignKey' => 'invoice_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
            )
        );

public $hasOne = array(
        'Sender' => array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey' =>'sender_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'accounts_id',),
        'Receiver'=> array(
            'className' => 'Account',
            'foreignKey' =>'receiver_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'accounts_id',
            )
            );
```

disputes has one sender and one receiver as one invoice can have only one dispute.

Comment: Var $id return with corrct value?

Comment: and return some error after the query? Have you checked it?like field not found, table not found?

Comment: no error, just the array returns null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code if you are into DisputeController:
I don't know if the table name is invoices

```
 $id = $this->Auth->User('account_id');

$options['joins'] = array(    
    array(
            'table' => 'invoices',
            'alias' => 'i',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(            
                'i.id' => 'invoice_id',  
                    'i.receiver_id' => $id      
                )    
      ));

 $receiver = $this->Dispute->find('all', $options);

  $this->set('id',$id);
  $this->set('receiver', $receiver);
```

Comment: In your view try to print the query like this if you have allowed this option: <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?> and see the query if some field are empty or not good

Comment: To show the SQL statements, be sure you have the following set in core.php

Configure::write('debug', 2); and in your view put the code: echo $this->element('sql_dump');  in this mode you print all your query in sql format

Comment: i have this  in the view <?php echo $this->$receiver('sql_dump'); ?> and my debug is set to 2

Comment: $this->element('sql_dump'); try with that and don't with receiver

Comment: i get this error when refresing, line 34 is the line of the sql dump  ) Fatal error: Method name must be a string in C:\wamp\www\pra\app\View\Disputes\index_admin.ctp on line 34

Comment: if you take the sql output and try to put into your sql client (like phpmyadmin) return error, rows or empty?

Comment: in phpmyadmin it produces empty

Comment: try to change into phpmyadmin into your sql Dispute.invoice_id with an existent invoice_id and if is empty the result try to change the join to LEFT to INNER and see if return some records

Comment: changing all left joints to inner joins results in 0 return

Comment: and insert Dispute.invoice_id a real invoice_id?

Comment: sorry, it does work. changing them all to inner and setting the dispute.invoice_id to a value in the database does return a value.(long day)

Comment: it's the result that you want? if yes you have to change the method of join into cakephp from left to inner

Comment: perfect you have only now to change in inner join

Comment: I have edit my question I don't know is perfectly but you can start with taht to retrieve your data

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Sender.sender_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: I have seen but sender what is in your database?

Comment: its referring to the models, i'll update the code up the top with relevant information on database and models.

Comment: I don't know if is weel and if works, but try to put this before the code: $this->Dispute->recursive = 2;

Answer (score 0):

```
public function index_admin(){

     $id = $this->Auth->User('account_id');


    $this->Invoice->bindModel(array('hasMany'=>array('Dispute' => array ('className' => 'Dispute','foreignKey' => 'invoice_id'))));

    $receiver = $this->Invoice->find('all',array('conditions'=>array('Invoice.receiver_id'=>$id)));

    $this->set('id',$id);
    $this->set('receiver', $receiver);

  }
```

============ Updated Answer ================

```
public function index_admin(){

  $id = $this->Auth->User('account_id');


  $this->Invoice->bindModel(array('hasMany'=>array('Dispute' => array ('className' => 'Dispute','foreignKey' => 'invoice_id','conditions'=>array('receiver_id'=>$id)))));

   $receiver = $this->Invoice->find('all');

   $this->set('id',$id);
  $this->set('receiver', $receiver);

 }
```

Try my updated answer and let me know

Comment: it prints out invoices that don't have disputes.

Comment: @user1393064: please check record dispute.invoice_id=invoice.id in disputes table

Comment: have checked it's printing out 5 records and should only print out 3

Comment: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Invoice.receiver_id' in 'where clause'